# Python re.findall getting value

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file which have multi lines in the same following pattern

```
Server:x.x.x # U:100 # P:100 # Pre:00 # Tel:xxxxxx
```

I built this code to get the value after Pre:

```
x2 = (re.findall(r'Pre:(\d+)',s))
```

I'm not so familiar with re patterns , but this code don't get the value if it is + or empty value ( a None value )

Any suggestions to generlize the code to get what ever value after `Pre:` until the next # without the space ?

Comment: You've shown us only an example that _does_ work. You should show us examples that do _not_ work. What exactly do you mean with "+ or empty value"?

Answer (score 1):

How about this as the pattern? It will get everything until the next `" #"` but without being greedy (that's what the `?` is for).

```
r"Pre:(.*?) #"
```

Answer (score 0):

The example you've provided works just fine:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'Server:x.x.x # U:100 # P:100 # Pre:00 # Tel:xxxxxx'
>>> re.findall(r'Pre:(\d+)', s)
['00']
```

You may need to add handling of `+/-` and `.,` for negative numbers and decimals: `(-?[\d.,]+)`.

If you need to match any string (not just numbers) you may want to use `Pre:(.*?)\s*#`.

Or you may avoid using regexps at all and split row by `#` separator:

```
>>> s.split('#')
['Server:x.x.x ', ' U:100 ', ' P:100 ', ' Pre:00 ', ' Tel:xxxxxx']
```

And then split rows by first `:`:

```
>>> for row in s.split('#'):
...     k, v = row.split(':', 1)
...     print(k.strip(), '=', v.strip())
... 
Server = x.x.x
U = 100
P = 100
Pre = 00
Tel = xxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

A *non-regex approach* would involve splitting by `#` and then by `:` forming a dictionary which would make accessing the parts of the string easy and readable:

```
>>> s = "Server:x.x.x # U:100 # P:100 # Pre:00 # Tel:xxxxxx"
>>> d = dict([key.split(":") for key in s.split(" # ")])
>>> d["Pre"]
'00'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x2 = (re.findall(r'Pre:(.*?) #',s))
```

---

```
Pre:(.*?) #
```

> Match the character string “Pre:” literally «Pre:» Match the regex
>   below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.*?)»
>
>   Match any single character that is NOT a line break character «.*?»
>         Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
>   Match the character string “ #”
>   literally « #»